# Greedy algorithm for trading cryptocurrencies with perfect price information

Tags: algorithms, decision-problem, greedy-algorithms, knapsack-problems

Assume the following hypothetic scenario:

> You know the values $v_1^0, \ldots, v_n^0$ of $n$ cryptocurrencies. You know the values this currencies will have for the following $m$ days; this is, $v_0^1, \ldots, v_n^1$ up to $v_1^m, \ldots, v_n^m$. In general, $v_{i}^j$ is the value
> of the $i$th currency in $j$ days from today.

---

We want to implement a greedy algorithm that finds the maximum possible gain obtainable in $m$ days. Each day we can buy and sell currencies. We have an initial amount of money $D$. Importantly, we are allowed to buy and sell *fractions* of a currency.

The problem is very similar to the fractional knapsack problem, where we must maximize value with a weight limit, and we can store fractions of the objects in the knapsack. It has, however, a frew differences:

1. We can buy and sell, so there are two possible actions (instead of just one in the knapsack problem, "store something in the knapsack");
2. The values of the objects in question change.

My main issue is to find a good selection criteria. I thought a good criteria would be the following. For each object, there is a maximum gain ratio $v_i^{\max} / v_i^{\min}$; the ratio between its value at its highest price and at its lowest price, assuming $\max > \min$ (we can sell it at high price *after* buying it at low price). The best strategy, it seems to me, would be to buy as much of the currency $v_i$ on day $v_i^{\min}$ and to sell it on day $v_i^{\max}$.

This criteria has a few issues however. For example, it doesn't contemplate buying different types of currency on the same day. I was unable to think of a better criteria though. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you sell currencies you do not yet own?

Comment: http://quant.stackexchange.com may be a better home for this question